# Frontend image upload in Typo3 7.4

Tags: file, upload, typo3, frontend

I'm developing an extension (and website) for a friend who needs to make different profiles for people, comparable to an intranet or online address-book.

The extension works almost great, but I'd like to have an option to upload profile pictures at the frontend in the create and edit action.

The example of [Helhum on Github](https://github.com/helhum/upload_example) somehow doesn't work on Typo3 7.4. It tells me

```
An error occurred while trying to call Helhum\UploadExample\Controller\ExampleController->createAction()
image:
Object with identifier "1:/content/" does not exist in storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be that you do not have that folder. You can try with default user upload folder like:

> UploadedFileReferenceConverter::CONFIGURATION_UPLOAD_FOLDER =>
>   '1:/user_upload/'

Comment: this has nothing to do with a real 'folder'.  FAL uses storages: a virtual directory to group assets. the error says that the storage record with UID 1 does not exist.  create a storage folder (in your root) so you will have a storage record with uid1

Comment: I have recreated the same thing, and UploadedFileReferenceConverter::CONFIGURATION_UPLOAD_FOLDER => '1:/user_upload/' works, while UploadedFileReferenceConverter::CONFIGURATION_UPLOAD_FOLDER => '1:/content/' do not works. And I have storage record with ID 1 (default instalation). Are yousure this is problem?